# How get average and sum of a cell with two numbers containing a dash in the middle?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a column containing values **(1.25-1.50)**, I need to get the average and sum of these two from a single cell containing dash in the middle. Using Excel.

Comment: Note that using a "-" as the separator for the two values will cause problems unless both values are positive. A comma or other character might be safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd extract the two numbers. The key here is to use `find` to locate the `-` in the cell, and then `left` and `right` to extract the values around it. Note that since you want to treat these as numbers, you need to use `value` to convert the text to numbers:

Assuming the value is in A1, the left-hand side could be extracted by:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1, FIND("-", A1) - 1))
```

Similarly, the right-hand side could be extracted by:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-", A1)))
```

Assuming you have these two result in B1 and C1, respectively, finding their average and sum should be straight forward now that we've done the heavy lifting:

```
=AVERAGE(B1:C1)
=SUM(B1:C1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it in one formula use SUMPRODUCT and parse the string:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99},99)))
```

That will return the sum.  To get the average just divide by `2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99},99)))/2
```

[image]